# A button to scroll at the top of the page in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css, html

Below Playground I have code with the button to scroll at the top of the page and conditionally render the button when user scrolled down. Now if I remove the custom render thing then button works as expected but when I add the custom css for conditional rendering then button stopped working,

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qKcmUdV9o/19/edit)

On above playground when you scroll down, a button will appear at the bottom left but when you click on it won't scroll at the top.

Answer (score 6):

You can even use `window.scrollTo` option, if you want to scroll till top.

```
topFunction(){
    const scrollOptions = {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    }
    window.scrollTo(scrollOptions);
}
```

HTML (add this at end):

```
<lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:arrowup" class="topButton" onclick={topFunction}
                       variant="brand" alternative-text="ArrowUp">
</lightning-button-icon>
```

CSS:

```
.topButton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.topButton:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this in goToTop function remove everything else

```
  this.template.querySelector('.test').scrollTop=0;
```

and in the html class assign class name test like

```
<div class='test' style="overflow: auto; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; " onscroll={onScroll}>
```

Comment: it is working as expected in the playground but in real time I am getting this error 
Uncaught TypeError: this.template.querySelectorAll(...)[0].scrollTo is not a function, could you please suggest on it

Comment: i have updated my answer @gs650x

Comment: Thank you, but we cannot add scroll behavior with this.

Comment: can you share your code.i just deployed this its working fine for me

Comment: It works fine but how to add scroll behavior with the same?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qKcmUdV9o/35/edit

Answer (score 1):

To make the scrollTop = 0 to work the container div has to have an internal scroll. Which we can get by either giving a height via px or via vh.

Try that out it should work. I was facing a similar issue while adding LWC inside Flexi Page. The Flexi page has its own scroller but for that, the scrollTop doesn't work. But if we create a separate scroller at the top-level div then the scrollTop starts to work.

Check this out. I have created this and it works perfectly fine for me:
https://webcomponents.dev/edit/3vpWJ46hxykfPSACfuNN

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.