# How to scroll on the top of modal

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

i have a modal popup with scrolling, i am trying to scroll the user to the top of the modal when the user clicks on a button.
window.scrollTo(0,0) is scrolling the main window not the modal.

Comment: what do you think `window.scrollTo(0,0)` is acting upon?

Comment: on the main window, means the behind one.

Answer (score 0):

You should select your modal window specificly and use the scroll on it.
Please see if this article would help it seems fairly straightforward:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910362/how-to-scroll-to-the-top-of-a-modal-window-in-javascript

Also keep in mind that in LWC you might be missing some JS libaries described in the help article.

Here is another one made specificly for LWC:

[A button to scroll at the top of the page in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284409/a-button-to-scroll-at-the-top-of-the-page-in-lwc)

Comment: Hello, any idea how to achieve similar behaviour in salesforce mobile app?